# Generating vectors in a non-orthogonal 3D lattice with increasing magnitude

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, integer-lattices

I am trying to build an algorithm to generate a sequence of lattice vectors $\mathbf{v}_n$ in 3D such that:

(a) the first vector $|\mathbf{v}_1|$ is the shortest vector of the lattice

(b) for all $i \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $\mathbf{v}_{i+1}$ is the shortest lattice vector greater than $\mathbf{v}_{i}$

So the sequence $\mathbf{v}_n$ not only contains lattice vectors of increasing magnitude but also has the property that there does not exist any lattice vector $\mathbf{v}$ such that $|\mathbf{v}_i| < |\mathbf{v}| < |\mathbf{v}_{i+1}|$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$.

The basis vectors of the general non-orthogonal 3D lattice may be denoted as $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$. **Note that the basis vectors have been passed through an LLL algorithm, so they are short and as close to orthogonal as possible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_reduction).** The magnitude of the lattice vector $\mathbf{v}$ is:

$|\mathbf{v}|^2 = \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{v} = \left[ u\mathbf{a}, \, u\mathbf{b}, u\mathbf{c} \right]^T \left[ u\mathbf{a}, \, u\mathbf{b}, u\mathbf{c} \right]$

where $u, v, w \in \mathbb{Z}$ and are the components of the vector $\mathbf{v}$ in the lattice.

I was able to get a simple solution for 2D with orthogonal basis vectors but I was not able to think of any good solution even in 2D for non-orthogonal vectors. I wanted to post this question to see if this is a well-known problem (or some variant of a well-known problem) or if anyone had already thought about something like this before.

For the Gram matrix (specified by Will Jaggy):

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 5 \end{array} \right)$

the first 20 shortest vectors will be:

```
-1     0     0
 0    -1     0
 0     1     0
 1     0     0
-1    -1     0
-1     1     0
 1    -1     0
 1     1     0
 0     0    -1
 0     1    -1
 1     0    -1
 1     1    -1
-1    -1     1
-1     0     1
 0    -1     1
 0     0     1
-2     0     0
 0    -2     0
 0     2     0
 2     0     0
```

The square of the Euclidean norms, i.e. $||v||^2$,for the first 20 vectors are: 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 8

Comment: Srikanth, I put a 3 by 3 Gram matrix in my answer. What this indicates, for basis vectors $a,b,c$ is that $a \cdot a = 2,$ $b \cdot b = 2,$  $c \cdot c = 5,$ $b \cdot c = 1,$   $c \cdot a = 1,$ $a \cdot b = 0.$ Please find the first ten items that you would want for your sequence, and edit those into your question. I currently have little idea what you want, and I suspect you are attempting to get an algorithm for a task you have never done by some slow method.

Comment: I added the first 20 vectors in the sequence for the Gram Matrix you specified. The code I use is very inefficient and not guaranteed to give the right answer but it works in most cases. I just create a 3D-mesh of points, e.g. $u, v, w \in [-10, 10]$ and I gave you the first 20 vectors after sorting the distances for all the generated vectors. This will clearly not work well for skewed bases. Thank you.

Comment: I can finally make one substantial comment: in order to find all $|v|^2$ up to some bound $M,$ we get a guaranteed search by using lagrange multipliers to maximize $|u|,$   $|v|,$   $|w|,$ under the constraint i mentioned, $$ X^T G X \leq M $$

Comment: @Will: Interesting.. Just so we are on the same page, I will first find max $|u|$, $|v|$, and $|w|$ using Lagrange multipliers with the constraint $X^T G X \leq M$. Then I will check the norms for all the vectors with $u \in [-|u|, |u|]$, $v \in [-|v|, |v|]$ and $w \in [-|w|, |w|]$ and pick all the vectors satisfying the constraint $X^T G X \leq M$. I agree that this will give me all the vectors $|v|^2$ up to some bound $M$.

Comment: Yes, and the gradient of $X^T G X,$ written as a column vector, is $2 G X.$ The gradient of, say, $u,$ is $(1,0,0)^T.$ Anyway, the main computation for Lagrange is to find $G^{-1}$ and go from there. It is also fine to use the adjoint matrix for $G,$ as it is just a multiple of the inverse.

Comment: Thank you, Will. I can definitely do this. If you put this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a guaranteed way to find all vectors with squared norm up to some bound $M.$ Find the Gram matrix $G$ of the lattice. Write the squared norm of any column vector as $X^T G X,$ where the entries of $X$ are the coefficients of the basis vectors. Note that the set 
$$ X^T G X \leq  M  $$
is an ellipsoid. If we call $X = (u,v,w),$ the gradient of the function $u$ is just $e_1 = (1,0,0)^T.$ In order to find the maximum possible $u$ on the ellipsoid, just solve Lagrange multipliers. Written as a column vector, the gradient of $X^T G X$ is just
$$ 2 G X. $$
As a result, the only important matrix calculation here is finding $G^{-1};$ it is satisfactory to use the adjoint matrix of $G,$ because that is just a multiple of the inverse.

In total, to get all vectors with squared norm  up to some $M,$ we can just use Lagrange multipliers to give a firm upper bound for $|u|,$ another upper bound for   $|v|,$ another upper bound for   $|w|.$ This defines a rectangular brick shape that completely contains the ellipsoid.

FROM MY BIG BOOK O' QUADRATIC FORMS

Jonathan Hanke once asked me how I got nice bounds on the variables in
programming a computer search on the ellipsoid $T(x,y,z) \leq M$
for some large positive $M,$
where
$  T(x,y,z) = a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 + d y z + e z x + f x y $
is a positive ternary.
Well,
$$  
T(x,y,z) = 
\left( x \: y \: z \right) \cdot
\left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  a & f/2 & e/2\\
  f/2 & b & d/2\\
  e/2 & d/2 & c  
\end{array} 
  \right)  \cdot
\left(  \begin{array}{c}
  x \\
  y\\
  z  
\end{array} 
  \right) .
  $$
It is simple enough to confirm that the gradient of $T,$ written
as a column vector, is 
$$  
\nabla T(x,y,z) = 
\left(  \begin{array}{c}
2 a x + f y + e z \\
  f x + 2 b y + d z  \\
  e x + d y + 2 c z  
\end{array} 
  \right) =
2 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  a & f/2 & e/2\\
  f/2 & b & d/2\\
  e/2 & d/2 & c  
\end{array} 
  \right)  \cdot
\left(  \begin{array}{c}
  x \\
  y\\
  z  
\end{array} 
  \right) .
  $$

We are going to use the method of Lagrange multipliers. It
follows from the compactness of the ellipsoid $T \leq M$
(the Gram matrix has positive eigenvalues)
that any of the variables $x,y,z$ achieves its maximum.
It follows from the strict convexity of the ellipsoid that
these maxima are achieved at boundary points where $T = M.$
Finally it follows from the smoothness of the boundary 
that Lagrange multipliers will locate all such points.

Give a name $F$ to the matrix,
so
$$ F = 
\left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
  a & f/2 & e/2\\
  f/2 & b & d/2\\
  e/2 & d/2 & c  
\end{array} 
  \right) . 
  $$

We need the other gradients,
$$
\nabla x = 
\left(  \begin{array}{c}
1\\
  0 \\
  0 
\end{array} 
  \right) = e_1,
\nabla y = 
\left(  \begin{array}{c}
0\\
  1 \\
  0 
\end{array} 
  \right) = e_2,
\nabla z = 
\left(  \begin{array}{c}
0\\
  0 \\
  1 
\end{array} 
  \right) = e_3 .
$$

So, given
$$
X = 
\left(  \begin{array}{c}
x\\
  y \\
  z 
\end{array} 
  \right) ,
$$

we are solving the system
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 F X  &  = & \lambda e_i \\
 X' F X  &=  &M
 \end{array}
 $$
$X' = (x \: y \: z)$ being the transpose of $X.$

The matrix $F$ has an inverse that we will cleverly name $F^{-1}.$
So we find
$$ X =\left( \frac{\lambda}{2}  \right) F^{-1} e_i .$$

The fraction doesn't help or hurt, so we will name 
$ t =  \left( \frac{\lambda}{2}  \right) $ and get
 $$ X =t F^{-1} e_i .$$

Notice that $F$ and so $F^{-1}$ are symmetric.
Next we use $  X' F X  =  M, $
or $ t {e_i}'  F^{-1} F  F^{-1} e_i t = M,$
whence
 $ t {e_i}' F^{-1} e_i t = M.$
 Now $  {e_i}' F^{-1} e_i $ is the $i,i$ entry of $ F^{-1},$
 which we write as $ F^{-1}_{ii}.$
 So we find
 $$t^2F^{-1}_{ii}  = M.  $$
 or
 $$ t = \sqrt{ \frac{M}{ F^{-1}_{ii}}  }.$$

Recalling $ X =t F^{-1} e_i $  gives us
$$ X =
\left(  \begin{array}{c}
t  F^{-1}_{1i}\\
t  F^{-1}_{2i}  \\
t  F^{-1}_{3i}  
\end{array} 
  \right) ,
$$

So, maximizing $x_1 = x, x_2 = y, x_3 = z$ leads us to the value
$$ x_i =  t  F^{-1}_{ii} =  \sqrt{ \frac{M}{ F^{-1}_{ii}}  }  F^{-1}_{ii} ,$$
or $$ x_i =  \sqrt{ M F^{-1}_{ii}  }  $$

In conclusion,
$$ | x | \leq  \sqrt{ M F^{-1}_{11}}, \hspace{7mm}
 | y | \leq  \sqrt{ M F^{-1}_{22}},  \hspace{7mm}
 | z | \leq  \sqrt{ M F^{-1}_{33}}.  $$

If supreme efficiency is needed, one then fixes, say, a value
of $z,$ and notes that the ellipsoid section described
is an ellipse. The Lagrange multiplier method can
be repeated to find, say, the maximum and minimum of $y,$
which are no longer of the same absolute value.
Finally, with values of $y,z$ chosen, bounds
on $x$ come from the quadratic formula.

I worked up an example to illustrate the possible need.
What follows is an ellipsoid of revolution of a cigar shape,
long in the direction of the vector (1,1,1) and narrow in any
orthogonal direction. As a result, the volume of the cube given
by the bounds
$
 | x | \leq  \sqrt{ M F^{-1}_{11}}, 
 | y | \leq  \sqrt{ M F^{-1}_{22}},
 | z | \leq  \sqrt{ M F^{-1}_{33}} $ is quite large
 compared with the volume of the ellipsoid.
The volume of the ellipsoid is very close to the number
of integer triples to be checked that satisfy $T(x,y,z) \leq M.$
Think about it.

Given a large integer $W > 0,$
let 
$$ 
  \begin{array}{ccc}
T(x,y,z) & = & ( x + y + z)^2 + 3 W ( x - y)^2 + W ( x + y - 2 z)^2\\
 & = &  ( 4 W + 1)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) - (4 W - 2) (y z + z x + x y). 
\end{array} 
$$
In the ellipsoid $ T \leq 9 W^2,$ we find the integer point $(W,W,W),$
at a distance of
 $ \sqrt{ W^2 + W^2 + W^2 } = W  \sqrt{3}$ from the origin.
However, in the plane $x + y + z = 0,$ we get a circular section
of the ellipsoid, and letting $t$ now be the distance of
a point from the origin, taking $ x = t / \sqrt{2} ,
 y = -t / \sqrt{2} , z = 0$ tells us that 
 $ \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 } \leq \sqrt{\frac{3 W}{2}}.$
 Anyway much smaller than $W \sqrt{3}.$

As to the comparison of volumes, the cube given by the
raw $x,y,z$ bounds has volume at least $ 8 W^3,$ being at
least $2 W $ on a side. Using the discriminant recipe
$ \Delta = 4 a b c + d e f - a d^2 - b e^2 - c f^2 $
gives $\Delta = 432 W^2.$
The volume of the ellipsoid  $ T \leq M$ should be
$$ \frac{8 \pi M^{3/2}}{ 3 \sqrt{\Delta}}  .$$
With $ T \leq 9 W^2,$ we have $ M = 3 W^2,$ so
the ellipsoid has volume $ 2 \pi \sqrt{3} W^2.$
Finally the volume of the cube divided by the
volume of the cigar is
$$  \frac{4 W}{\pi \sqrt{3}} = \left( \frac{4}{\pi \sqrt{3}} \right) W,$$
a bit larger than $ \frac{11 W}{ 15}.$

END O' EXCERPT

There are roughly 1000 positive ternary forms for which all represented numbers (all lattice norms) are known, with proofs. In every other case, it is a matter of luck. What that means for you is that your task can be done up to some finite bound without difficulty, it is a finite check because the form  is positive definite, the Gram matrix has a minimum eigenvalue and so on, but no infinite sequence, no algorithm.

I have always used Schiemann's reduction in my articles. This is a slight refinement of Eisenstein's reduction that moves all positive ternary forms into a single cone in $\mathbb R^6.$

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002080050086

http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=6992372

Tell you what: by any means available to you, please find the first ten entries in an acceptable sequence for the lattice with the following Gram matrix:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Just so you know, the form I specify is in the same genus as $x^2 + y^2 + 16 z^2.$ As you can see from Dickson's book below, we know exactly what numbers occur as squared norms of vectors in the $(1,1,16)$ lattice. The extra ingredient I put in, on purpose, that the form with the Gram matrix above also fails to represent $1,25,169,..., $ indeed any $m^2$ where all prime factors $p$ of $m$ satisfy $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$

[image]

Comment: Hi Will... I have to admit, I am not a math major and I tried to read the papers from the links you have provided and failed to link it to my question. I did some more online research and found this question to be very relevant to what I am looking for: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9792/the-n-shortest-lattice-vectors-problem-in-mathcalr2. The problem in this link is in 2D and I am looking for something in 3D. I am looking for a finite sequence of vectors. If you could explain the algorithm, that will be great help.

Comment: @Srikanth, so, what is your actual major? And why do you want this sequence of vectors?

Comment: I will get you the 10-shortest vectors in the next hour or so as I am in the process of developing some brute-force code. Also, I am a material science major. My materials are crystalline, which means that the atoms sit on a prescribed lattice. The short vectors have some nice properties for simulating a phenomena that I am interested in.

Comment: Thanks, Will... Your answer is very helpful.

Comment: The more I read it, the more I appreciate your answer and how well written it is. Excellent! Thank you.